# Elastic Search Mapping inconsistency Error

Tags: elasticsearch

I have issued a query in elasticsearch in spark scala and getting following error. Any one has any idea why we will get this kind of error. I tried to google it and didn't get any clue.

Here is my query:

```
{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"range":{"date":{"gte":"1527577200000","lte":"1527606000000","format":"epoch_millis"}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"keyword":"name=cat"}}]}}],"
must_not":[]}}
```

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Position for
>   'xxxx' not found in row; typically this is caused by a mapping
>   inconsistency at
>   org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.RowValueReader$class.addToBuffer

Comment: Could you show your doc mapping?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. I am new to elasticsearch and what do you mean by doc mapping.